# Haproxy: How to balance traffic within directory reached?

Tags: load-balancing, http, haproxy, request

I want to know if there's a way to balance the traffic within directories using haproxy.

I have haproxy balancing all HTTP traffic to `server1` & `server2`. What I want is to balance all `images` directory requests to `server1`

e.g.

```
url: http://www.domain.com/images/image_one.jpg
url: http://www.domain.com/images/image_two.jpg
url: http://www.domain.com/images/image_three.jpg
```

All this requests must go to server1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare an `acl` and then do a conditional `use_backend` statement. Like this:

```
frontend a-frontend-conf

    # Declare an ACL using path_beg (Path Begins)
    acl path_images path_beg /images

    # Use backend server1 if acl condition path_images is fulfilled
    use_backend server1 if path_images

backend server1
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, assuming you already have a backend defined for `server1` & `server2`, would be to do the static server selection in the backend, thusly:

```
frontend a-frontend-conf

    # Declare an ACL using the 'Host' header
    acl host_domain hdr(host) -i www.domain.com
    # Use backend 'farm' if acl condition host_domain is fulfilled
    use_backend farm if host_domain 

backend farm
    acl path_images path_beg /images
    use-server server1 if path_images
    server server1 1.1.1.1:80 
    server server2 2.2.2.2:80
```